# Apache Spark: Understanding terminology of Driver and Executor Configuration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, process, distributed-computing, cpu-cores

I have been seeing the following terms in every distributed computing open source projects more often particularly in Apache spark and hoping to get explanation with a simple example.

- spark.driver.cores - Number of cores to use for the driver process, only in cluster mode.
- spark.driver.memory   - Amount of memory to use for the driver process
- spark.executor.cores -    The number of cores to use on each executor
- spark.executor.memory - Amount of memory to use per executor process
- spark.task.cpus - Number of cores to allocate for each task.

For example, if there are three computers C1,  C2 and C3 with intel i5 processor(CPU) which has 4 cores(shorturl.at/apsSW) and assume 16 GB RAM and 1 TB secondary storage(mounted/in-built).

0. So, where does above mentioned terms would fit if I try to process 1 GB of CSV file using those three computers in spark cluster environment with YARN?

If we take C1 as master computer/server/node (Uff.. too many terms) and C2, C3 as slaves/workers/executers

On highlevel, I am thinking that (with an assumption that the file is not in C1, C2 or C3 but on some cloud storage) -
When we submit spark program(let's say the program about reading and displaying first row on drivers console) on driver(C1), it tells its executors(C2 and C3) to get the data from that CSV file through internet/intranet in partitions(if partitions are defined in program).

But,

1. don't know how driver cores and memory & executor cores and memory impact this entire process.
2. Oh.. coming to the term `process`, it is always been linked to cores. What exactly a `process` represent, does it represent process behind spark program?
3. And there comes, tasks.. are these tasks represent processes spawned from spark program?
4. And in cloud, there is a term vCPUs to confuse more, does vCPU corresponds to a single core?

Answer (score 0):

> So, where does above mentioned terms would fit if I try to process 1
> GB of CSV file using those three computers in spark cluster
> environment with YARN?

[By default](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) you would have a driver randomly assigned to one of those three `nodes`.(with 1 gig of memory, 1 core) and 2(if I remember correctly) executors assigned (with 1 gig of memory each 1 core each)

Of course all of this is configurable but it's best to stick to defaults until you run out of memory.

> don't know how driver cores and memory & executor cores and memory
> impact this entire process.

Good, leave it alone until you run out of memory/need more performance.  Don't pre-tune your config.  Wait until there is a performance issue then solve that.  Way to often people assign 8 gigs 8 cores to a process and use 50k and 1 core. There are settings to tune performance later when it's an issue.  Know that there there, and when you run into an issue then start to tweak them.

> h.. coming to the term process, it is always been linked to cores.
> What exactly a process represent, does it represent process behind
> spark program?

I don't really get the ask.  Computation take resources. You need space or cores to process information.

> And there comes, tasks.. are these tasks represent processes spawned
> from spark program?

A task is a unit of work defined by the program you write.  Look into the spark UI and it will give you some intuition as to how things work.

> And in cloud, there is a term vCPUs to confuse more, does vCPU
> corresponds to a single core?

It allows you to define the number of cores on a machine.  You can underprescibe or over prescribe them to a `node`, depends on your needs.  For now imagine them as your way to define what the node has availble, and that spark will interpret them as cores.